# How to check focus is out of editor in editable cell in a Ext JS grid

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs, celleditorlistener

I have an editable Ext Grid with checkbox selection model. When I select checkbox the cellediting is disabled and when cell is edited then checkbox selection is disabled. 
My issue is that I am not able to capture the blur/focus out event of cell editing. Means when I edit the cell and without clicking anywhere else I click on Checkbox, both (cellediting and checkbox are disabled) actions are performed.

How should I capture the on blur or focus out event of cell editing. {Ext 4.1.3}

Comment: create some fiddle which can describe your problem

Comment: can you provide your efforts here **[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)**?